# Use CSS custom properties at SCSS variables

Tags: sass

```
$color:        var(--primary-color, #333);
```

I tested this code by use SCSS web essential compiler and didn't work, but just wonder anyone else had used CSS custom properties in this way before or not. If I can do this, I don't have to change lots of code use this $color.

Comment: What you mean by “didn’t work”?

Comment: Its an interesting ask, I don't know the answer but if I had to guess I would say the SASS precompiler is not setup to breakdown css custom props.

Comment: I figure out something, looks like sass compiler doesn't support CSS custom with darken, so just $color: var(--primary-color) works if the $color don't use with darken($color, 10%). that makes sense since CSS custom props are dynamic, but I hope I could do that so I don't have to modify the code in many places.